# Is there a built-in login template in Django?

Tags: django, authentication, templates

I want to let a user sign in before seeing pages. Is there any built-in template for user sign in, so that I do not have to write my own sign in page?

Comment: 'Django provides **no default template** for the authentication views. You should create your own templates for the views you want to use.'

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes. You can read all about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required ... but here are some bullet points:

- add `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` to `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py`
- add `'django.contrib.auth`' and `'django.contrib.contenttypes'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`
- setup a URL for the login using `django.contrib.auth.views.login` for the view, such as `url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',name="my_login")`
- In your view, include the login_required decorator and add it before your view. For example...

views.py...

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
  return HttpResponse('Home Page')
```

By default, you then put the template inside `my_template_directory/registration/login.html` . Further info about that template can be found at the link in the beginning of this post.

Comment: Thanks for the information.

I get an exceptioN: TemplateDoesNotExist

However, the admin login page (also from template folder) exists.

Comment: you can pass in a 'template_name':'path/to/your/template.html' argument in the urlconf to be sure that it's trying to read the template from the correct place

Comment: @stanleyxu2005 if you want to use the default template, you need to actually create it in a subfolder of your templates directory.

Comment: The django "logout" template does exist, only the "login" template cannot be found. I am stilling diving

Comment: Thanks all of you. I have solved this problem by using the admin login/logout templates for normal users.

    # the built-in sign-in/out module 
    (r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
    (r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'admin/login.html'}),
    (r'^accounts/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/'}),
    (r'^accounts/profile/$', 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/'}),

Comment: Would you mind to explain a little better what you have done to use the django admin templates on the login/logout views?

Comment: In case anyone else found that admin suggestion useful, the correct redirect for urls.py in Django 1.5+ is: `url(r'^accounts/profile/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
url(r'^accounts/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),`

Comment: @JRicardo000: I did a bit of tinkering and summarised all these comments into the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: My edit with the summary got rejected, so I'll submit it as two comments instead. Apologies for the formatting.

To use the login template that's built into the admin site, you'll need these imports for a start:

`from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url`
`from django.contrib import admin`
`from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView`

I'll put the guts in a separate comment.

Comment: `urlpatterns = patterns('',` ↵
`    # The admin app` ↵
`    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),` ↵
`    # As commented by @stanleyxu2005` ↵
`    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),` ↵
`    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'admin/login.html'}),` ↵
`    # As commented by @Pterosaur` ↵
`    url(r'^accounts/profile/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),` ↵
`    url(r'^accounts/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),` ↵
`    # your own URLs go here` ↵
`)`

Comment: "The template" - what template? That's precisely what the question is asking. There is no default template for authentication views according to the link you supplied and if you do not provide one, errors arise.

Comment: @alex, the suggestions above worked for me. This is my urls.py verbadim:

Comment: from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url 
from django.contrib import admin 
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView





from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

Comment: url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'admin/login.html'}),
    url(r'^accounts/profile/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
    url(r'^accounts/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
    
 ]

Comment: The link provides a `login.html` example.

Comment: I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16630428/707650) to a duplicate question very useful: this provides all the extra goodies such as a password change form as well (all in Django admin style).

Comment: This is a good **yet incorrect** answer. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) clearly states the short answer is **No**: "Django provides no default template for the authentication views. You should create your own templates for the views you want to use.".

Answer (score 39):

As mentioned in the comments by the author, the easiest way to do this is to add the following lines to `urls.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', login, {'template_name': 'admin/login.html'}),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', logout),
)
```

As far as I know, adding the `r'^accounts/$'` and `r'^accounts/profile/$'` URLs is not necessary unless user profile management is required.

As suggested by @mmatt in comments, set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'` in `settings.py` to avoid the default redirect to `/accounts/profile/` after login. See [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url) in Django settings documentation.

This should also still work in Django 2.x using `path` instead of `url` appropriately.

For Django 2.1 and above, [the function-based views have been removed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/#section-7) in favour of class-based views:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('accounts/login/', LoginView.as_view(template_name='admin/login.html')),
    ...
]
```

Comment: Set `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'` in your settings.py to redirect to a page other than /accounts/profile.

Comment: Support for string view arguments in `url()` [has been removed with Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10). Use `from import django.contrib.auth.views import login` and `url(r'^accounts/login/$', login, ...` instead (and similar for logout).

Answer (score 16):

The most [upvoted response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2867342/258772) by @brant is technically incorrect. Django provides default views to handle login functionality but per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) does not provide a template:

> Django provides no default template for the authentication views. You should create your own templates for the views you want to use. The template context is documented in each view, see All authentication views.

Comment: Can anyone provide a working example of a login template?  I have this one (https://gist.github.com/mellertson/05b36bc929fa4667c77010cf5932de0d)  But, I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: Murphie's law prevails again, because no sooner did I post my comment when I found a working example in the Django docs.  I updated my gist code (above) so it now contains the example from the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Answer (score 8):

Similar to mrts’ answer, in more recent Django, you can use the [LoginView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView).
You can further customize the template by setting template context like `title`, `site_title` etc. as used in [admin/base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base_site.html) so that it doesn’t look like an admin login.

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView

urlpatterns = [
    url(  
        r'^accounts/login/$',  
        LoginView.as_view(
            template_name='admin/login.html',
            extra_context={         
              'title': 'Login',
              'site_title': 'My Site',
              'site_header': 'My Site Login'},
        name='login'),
]
```

Comment: For those who are looking for a sample template code, the `LoginView` mentioned in this answer does point to sample code for login.html

Answer (score 5):

If you want to take a quick route to getting up and running I recommend using the URLConf provided.

for example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url('^', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

See more details in the django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views

Comment: And a sample login template on the same page; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#all-authentication-views There seems to be no built-in ones? And no registration either, looks like you need a third party module for that: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/registration/

Comment: Self correction: some views do have built-in templates, like `accounts/password_reset/`, others don't like `accounts/login/`.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty.

Suppose, for example, you're working on a re-usable app that requires login functionality, but does not implement its own.

If, for the time being, you do not want to bother with custom login (views, forms, templates, urls, and so on), you can simply specify the admin login page as `LOGIN_URL` in `settings.py` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#login-url)):

```
...

LOGIN_URL = '/admin/login/'

...
```

Beware: One serious drawback is that you can only log in with a staff account (or superuser).