# Does Django ship with the authentication templates for use with the django.contrib.auth module?

Tags: python, django, django-contrib

I found some under the `tests` directory but I'm not sure if they are the right ones.

By authentication templates I mean `login.htm`, `password_reset.htm`, etc.

Some of the templates can be found at: http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it looks for those templates in a "registration" directory within your templates folder.

From the docs:

> It's your responsibility to provide the login form in a template called registration/login.html by default.
>
> Password Reset Optional arguments:
>
> > **template_name**: The full name of a template to use for displaying the password reset form. This will default to `registration/password_reset_form.html` if not supplied.

Docs: [login](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.login), [password_reset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset)

Comment: I vaguely remember that Django had these templates somewhere online on the Django site but I can't dig it up. There were templates for all the auth views.

Comment: That's interesting, I've actually never heard about or seen these. Are you sure it was on the Django site, and that you're not remembering the forms themselves?

Comment: I found it. They were here: http://devdoodles.wordpress.com/2009/02/16/user-authentication-with-django-registration/. The post is old but most of the forms work once you've added the CSRF token.

Comment: Django 2.0 does ship with built in templates for password reset. In fact, I am struggling to override them now.

Answer (score 19):

While the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views) explicitly states that "Django provides no default template for the authentication views", I found that it is trivial to use the admin templates. Just enable the admin app, then add this to urls.py:

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'admin/login.html'}),
url('^accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

All of the authentication urls work now, albeit with the Django admin look-and-feel.

Comment: `/login` result in `Unknown template variable <Variable: u'title'> title` - Django 1.9.2

Comment: Support for string view arguments in `url()` [has been removed with Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.10/#features-removed-in-1-10). Use `from import django.contrib.auth.views import login` and `url(r'^accounts/login/$', login, ...` instead.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the auth templates at [django.contrib.admin.templates.registration](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration):

```
logged_out.html
password_change_done.html
password_change_form.html
password_reset_complete.html
password_reset_confirm.html
password_reset_done.html
password_reset_email.html
password_reset_form.html
```

Those will have the look and feel of the Django Admin, so I would suggest to customize it.

Comment: How do you go about adding these to the project?

Comment: Just copy them to your template dir

Answer (score 6):

By copying the templates located in *django.contrib.admin.templates.registration* as mentioned by DZPM above  and placing them into your own registration app's templates directory e.g. *your_proj_root/registration/templates/registration/*

**IMPORTANT!** If you are keeping the same exact filenames for your templates, you have to remember to make sure that your *django.contrib.admin* app line is placed **below** your *registration* app line; otherwise, it will use the *django.contrib.admin*'s registration templates in preference.