# Django 1.6 and django-registration: built-in authentication views not picked up

Tags: django, django-registration, url-pattern, django-1.6

I am trying to upgrade my webapp from Django 1.5 to Django 1.6 and as part of my set of django apps I am using [django-registration 1.0](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration).

After upgrading to Django 1.6 my app does not recognize the [built-in authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#built-in-auth-views) any more. They are integrated in django registration as can be seen [here](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/8f242e35ef7c004e035e54b4bb093c32bf77c29f/registration/auth_urls.py?at=default), but they stopped working.

The Django release notes describe a [change in the way these views should be integrated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/releases/1.6/#miscellaneous), when comparing that to the source code in the registration-app that looks fine.

I am introducing the registration urls as follows:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
     ...,
     url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
```

I get the an error when requesting the built in urls such as `/accounts/password/change/`

```
django.core.urlresolvers.NoReverseMatch

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'password_change_done' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Does anyone have an idea why I get a no-reverse-match error?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The reason for this error is that the `django.contrib.auth.views` use different url names than the `registration.auth_urls` ones. To patch this problem, override the default urls until django-registration gets updated for django 1.6, and use the same names as Django.

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


urlpatterns = patterns('',

      #override the default urls
      url(r'^password/change/$',
                    auth_views.password_change,
                    name='password_change'),
      url(r'^password/change/done/$',
                    auth_views.password_change_done,
                    name='password_change_done'),
      url(r'^password/reset/$',
                    auth_views.password_reset,
                    name='password_reset'),
      url(r'^password/reset/done/$',
                    auth_views.password_reset_done,
                    name='password_reset_done'),
      url(r'^password/reset/complete/$',
                    auth_views.password_reset_complete,
                    name='password_reset_complete'),
      url(r'^password/reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>.+)/$',
                    auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
                    name='password_reset_confirm'),

      #and now add the registration urls
      url(r'', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
```

Comment: I added the code Jay listed above to my registration/backends/simple/urls.py . I guess if you are using the default you would add it to registration/backends/default/urls.py. That worked for me.

Comment: I did this also, and it works for me, however my templates are being ignored and the Django Admin templates are being used for password reset and change password.

Comment: There is an open pull request for this issue on the django-registration repository. I would assume it will be integrated in the next release. Follow the discussion here: https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/pull-request/63/

Comment: Macropin's [django-registration fork](https://github.com/macropin/django-registration) has this fix. `pip uninstall django-registration`, then `pip install -e git+https://github.com/macropin/django-registration#egg=django-registration`

Comment: P.s. I've asked the Django guys if they want to support django-registration, as providing the user/auth stuff seems incomplete without registration support, but they don't seem keen at the moment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/yawNAWE4d1o

Answer (score 8):

Here is what I used:

```py
url(r'', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
url(r'', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
```

Django contrib now includes the missing urls

Comment: This actually works fine for me at the moment. Will keep an eye on it though.

Answer (score 0):

**Background**

This issue seems to have cropped again for django-registration==1.0 and Django==1.6 and is documented [here](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/pull-request/63/django-16-compatibility-fix-auth-views/activity) on the official django-registration pull request.  I used the solution provided by @Jay but it didn't work specifically for the password reset part.  I ended up with this error:

**Error**

```
password_reset_confirm() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uidb36'
```

**Solution**

Instead I pulled from another django-registration repository (as mentioned in the official pull request above) by doing the following:

1. pip uninstall django-registration
2. pip install git+git://github.com/macropin/django-registration.git
3. Modify the code for 'urls.py' as mentioned in the post by @Jay (thanks!)
4. Remember this is a temporary solution until the official django-registration support is updated for Django 1.6

Comment: Isn't django-registration [no longer maintained](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/wiki/Home)? (I'd much rather this were made officially part of Django than South, but maybe that's something for 1.8!)

Comment: I'm hoping the django-registration is taken over by someone (or maybe it won't be).  I upgraded mine to 1.6 and since everything else was working, I used the fork to fix this issue.