# Django django-user-accounts default views not showing

Tags: python, django

This is my first django project. I'm trying to use https://github.com/pinax/django-user-accounts to add user accounts. I've followed the installation instructions. The database migrations have successfully run.

However when I visit http://localhost:8000/account/signup/ I get this

{# This template intentionally left blank to satisfy test suites. Your project should always provide a site_base.html itself. #}

I was expecting a default sign up page.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: As it says, It is a blank view just to start, you should create a `site_base.html` with your own style.

Comment: Some useful pointers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646400/authentication-templates-in-django

Comment: @Gocht Terrible question. Where should I put site_base.html. I tried putting it in the app-base/templates/site_base.html

Comment: Its documentation has a section about templates http://django-user-accounts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templates.html

Comment: @patrick_corrigan Same problem here. Have you made it work?