# What more do I need to do to have Django's @login_required decorator work?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I am trying to use Django's account system, including the @login_required decorator. My settings.py file includes `django.contrib.auth` and I have done a syncdb.

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/?next=/
Using the URLconf defined in dashboard.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$ [name='home']
The current URL, accounts/login/, didn't match any of these.
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

I see the above after trying to @login_required-decorate my home view.

It seems to be choking because it is redirected to accounts/login/, which I have not prepared for in my urls.py.

What can I add to urls.py or elsewhere so that the login_required decorator will do its usual behaviour?

Thanks,

Answer (score 24):

Set the [LOGIN_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url) in your settings. The default value is `'/accounts/login/'`

The decorator also takes an optional `login_url` argument:

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
```

And, from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/):

> Note that if you don’t specify the login_url parameter, you’ll need to
>   ensure that the settings.LOGIN_URL and your login view are properly
>   associated. For example, using the defaults, add the following line to
>   your URLconf:

```
(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

Comment: Thank you; I have added (what was unset before) a value of '/accounts/login/'. The behaviour is the same.

Comment: @KEYSER, thanks; I'm now getting "TemplateDoesNotExist at /accounts/login/"; it's looking for a "registration/login.html". Do I need to add something to my path?

Comment: Actually, there's a default: You can use the admin login template:

(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'admin/login.html'},name="my_login")

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867213/is-there-a-built-in-login-template-in-django

Comment: @Haroldo_OK yup! (for others, see the comments in [Haroldo's link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2867342/645270))

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in Django 2.2.1 - include `re_path('^accounts/', admin.site.urls),` in my project urls.py:

urls.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import re_path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path('^accounts/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And in my views.py:

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class HomePageView(TemplateView):
    """
    Home Page View
    """
    template_name = 'amp/home.html'
```

Hope that helps.

UPDATE: To avoid warnings from django in regards to admin urls being loaded twice, I used a redirect instead in urls.py:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('^accounts/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^admin/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/accounts/', permanent=True))
]
```

More on redirect view [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview).

Comment: this worked for me (new version of django ). Can u please add some explanation of `re_path(r'^admin/', RedirectView.as_view(url='/accounts/', permanent=True))`

Comment: I added a link to the doc on RedirectView.. you can also get where to redirect to via pattern_name and use a named url pattern from your app.

Answer (score 1):

```
path('accounts/login/', admin.site.urls),
```

Add this line in your `urls.py` project folder. Then it will work fine.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
```

Add above two lines in your `views.py` file.